# Question about df conditional selection using column.isnull() & column.str.len() > n

Tags: python, pandas

I’m wondering why the below conditional selection isn’t working.  I would expect indices 0 and 3 to be selected but this is returning nothing. Wondering if I’m missing something obvious.

```
In [5]: a = {'A':['this', 'is', 'an', 'example'], 'B':[None, None, None, None], 
   ...: 'C':['some', 'more', 'example', 'data']}

In [6]: df = pd.DataFrame(a)

In [7]: df
Out[7]: 
         A     B        C
0     this  None     some
1       is  None     more
2       an  None  example
3  example  None     data
```

This returns 2 rows:

```
In [8]: df.loc[(df['A'].str.len() > 3)]
Out[8]: 
         A     B     C
0     this  None  some
3  example  None  data
```

And this returns all rows:

```
In [9]: df.loc[(df['B'].isnull())]
Out[9]: 
         A     B        C
0     this  None     some
1       is  None     more
2       an  None  example
3  example  None     data
```

So I would expect this to return indices 0 and 3 but it doesn't return any rows

```
In [10]: df.loc[(df['B'].isnull() & df['A'].str.len() > 3)]
Out[10]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A, B, C]
Index: []
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Using the `Series/DataFrame` logical comparison operators can help cut down on all of the parentheses: `df.loc[df['B'].isnull() & df['A'].str.len().gt(3)]`

Comment: Yeah in Pandas it always wise to put paranthesis around each condition. (cond1) & (cond2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use separate brackets:

```
df.loc[(df['B'].isnull()) & (df['A'].str.len() > 3)]

         A     B     C
0     this  None  some
3  example  None  data
```

This is due to the [Operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence). In your code, `df['B'].isnull() & df['A'].str.len()` gets evaluated first, yielding:

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool
```

Then the remaining comparison `>3` is applied, yielding:

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```

And thus the original line returns no rows, instead of desired indices.

Answer (score 0):

It's a typo, the parenthesis have to be around the conditions, so use:

```
df.loc[(df['B'].isnull()) & (df['A'].str.len() > 3)]
```

Output:

```
         A     B     C
0     this  None  some
3  example  None  data
```